# Automatic generation of Unit test cases for .NET and Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, unit-testing, cyclomatic-complexity

Is there a good tool to generate unit test cases given say a .NET or Java project, it generates unit test cases that would cover an almost 100% code coverage.  The number of test cases could be directly proportional to the cyclomatic complexity of the code (the higher the nesting of loops and conditions the higher the cyclomatic complexity) where the higher the cyclomatic complexity, the greater the set of test cases are generated.  I'm not expecting it to be fully functional (say I'm going to build the unit tests and run it after its been generated), but I would say that it can have a template style in the test case where you are to modify the case that suits your intended needs.  But it should also have a proper setup and teardown method and is good enough to detect if mock objects for unit testing should be used should there be any dependencies.  So, is there such a tool that exists?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For .NET, Microsoft has [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) which will hopefully go mainstream for .NET 4.0, along with [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/). I highly recommend watching the Channel 9 video.

It strikes me that this sort of thing is very good for very data-driven classes - parsers etc. I can't see that I'd very often *start off* with it, but a useful tool to have in your armoury nonetheless.

Comment: What can I say, Marc? Either you've got it or you haven't... ;)

Comment: On "starting off" with it: Pex tests are more like executable specifications. Thinking of example input is really a boring job that is better handled by software...it knows about all the corner cases that the devloper is trying to ignore ;)

Comment: @Kurt: I think that makes sense for spotting edge/failure cases certainly. I think I'd normally start off with hand-written "success" cases though. Maybe I just need to use Pex in anger though to fully appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

For C# (or .NET in general), [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) might be that tool. It works at the IL level, and attempts to force its way into every branch. It has successfully uncovered a wide range of bugs (in the BCL etc).

Answer (score 5):

Although it seems counter-intuituve, you may also be interested in random test generation frameworks. Research has proven that it can be just as effective in finding bugs than systematic approaches based on coverage, as you suggest.

Check out [Randoop](http://people.csail.mit.edu/cpacheco/randoop/1.2/doc/) both for .NET and Java. It works by generating a more or less random sequence of method calls, and checks contracts, crashes etc. It is fully automatic.

Also you may want to check out some other random testing tools based on [QuickCheck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck), e.g. for Java, Scala, F#. that are more similar to Pex, i.e. you give a specification, or parametrized unit test, and the tool checks it for a number of generated input arguments.

I've found that this "parametrized" way of writing unit tests is actually a lot more natural in at least 60% of the cases, and finds lots more bugs.

Comment: The Randoop project webpage has moved to http://mernst.github.io/randoop/.

Answer (score 1):

For Java, you can check [EvoSuite](http://www.evosuite.org), which is open source and currently active (disclaimer, I am one of its contributors). Also see related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131935/automatic-generation-of-unit-tests-for-java?lq=1) for a list of more tools.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, try [JUnit-Tools](http://junit-tools.org/). It has own eclipse plugin along with good documentation.