# Testing the functionality of already compiled binaries

Tags: .net, testing, executable

Is there a library for testing the functionality of already compiled binaries? Something like unit tests but for already compiled executables, that should allow me to specify and verify rules regarding the behavior of the program for specific inputs and scenarios. I'm specifically interested in something targgetting the .NET platform, but I'd also like to know if there are platform-agnostic tools for this.

Comment: For .NET binaries, you can always use Reflector and then make your tests exactly how you want them ;-P

Comment: I know, I'm looking for a piece of software to facilitate this process.

Comment: I understand the question. Are you trying to use a testing tool (e.g. NUnit) on an already compiled binary? If so, what's the problem?

Comment: The question I would ask myself is "What happens when a test fails?"  If the answer is "fix it" then you need access to the source, in which case you may as well just test your source code from the start.

Comment: Nope, not fix it, but rather exploit it ;)

Comment: Oh, well that's a different story then.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689087/automatic-generation-of-unit-test-cases-for-net-and-java).  There are a lot of tools to automatically generate tests from a compiled .Net binary.  The biggest winner seems to be [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) which uses the [Z3](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/) constraint solving engine to explore the code.  In English, this means it can figure out what classes of input will cause each path of the code to execute.